# Android: Load implementations of interface across libraries using Guava

Tags: java, android, guava

I want to collect all implementations of concrete interface in my Android application. I've got something like this:

```
            List<T> list = ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
                    .getTopLevelClasses(Reflection.getPackageName(parent))
                    .stream()
                    .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
                    .filter(current -> isImplementation(parent, current))
                    .map(aClass -> (T) aClass)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but It always return 0 classes. Even if I want to retrieve all classes:

```
ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
                    .getAllClasses()
                    .stream()
                    .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's always zero. When I run it locally from my library in unit test it's ok. Probably, it's problem with `ClassLoader`. It doesn't provide informations about all packages provided by application.

**I don't want to use `DexFile` because it's [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile)** . There's no other information about `entries()` replacement function.

Is there any possibility to work around this?

Comment: Java isn't generally built to do anything like this, except via `ServiceLoader`, which has to be opted into.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I reach this by dagger dependency, I'll write down my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

You can use [dagger](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android) dependency (or newer, [hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)) to install components into one domain, such as `SingletonComponent` and inject it as constructor parameter by implementation. You can even inject multiple implementations as set.

Real answer:

I have created library `common` and `test`. Those libraries are pinned in my application.

1. In `common` module you can create any interface, like:

```
public interface Item {
}
```

2. Set dependency `common` to `test`. Reload dependencies. Now you can see `Item` in your `test` library. Write custom class that implements interface:

```
public class CustomItem implements Item{

//...

}
```

3. Create module in your `test` library:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class TestModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @IntoSet
    public Item customItem() {
        return new CustomItem();
    }

}
```

4. Set dependency `common` and `test` in application and add module with set of your implementations:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class ApplicationSingletonModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public CustomClassProvider customClassProvider(Set<Item> items) {
        return new CustomClassProvider(items);
    }
}
```

You can add multiple `Item` implementations and inject it across libraries without any problem.